# Google alerts api using node

Tags: node.js, google-alerts

I want to use Google Alerts API through node.

For that purpose i'm using one reference [github project](https://github.com/adasq/google-alerts-api). But i'm facing authentication issue, and it's not creating an alert.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have a look at this, hope it might help : https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65798/is-it-possible-to-get-the-google-alerts-as-structured-data

Comment: I've gone through the link that you have mentioned, but i didn't got any solution. Thanks for your efforts @KaranBhomia

Comment: I will be following this as I too am having the same issues.  I had this working 2-3 days ago per following the instructions of the cookie, and all of a sudden it doesn't authenticate.

I will be scouring other solutions for the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

I just now revisited the debugging of my problem and got it functioning how I had it...

The original README for the google-alerts-api was semi-vague in describing exactly how to retrieve (the correct) SID keys credentials to feed the "cookie maker".

Follow the steps to making a Cookie,   but you will log into Google Alerts, (not just your google account). Go into Alerts after you log into your google account, you will open the right click the page and open Inspector or aka Chromes Dev Tools.

When you are at the Google Alerts page to Create an alert,   create a "dev.to" alert and look for a line popup that contains "Create?x=" in the right Dev Tools ... it should show up after you create that alert.  This will show you the credentials that are used to interact with Google Alerts session and then click on it, and click Cookies.

This will show you the SSID SID and HSID to use for the cookie generator code.  I put that generator code in a different `gen.js` file,  not sure if this is OK, as I hope the session cookies don't expire (soon).  I run the generator, and it creates the cookie.data file.

I hope this helps...